# Create table form with jquery for multiple selections

Tags: php, html, css

I have this loop which outputs data:

```
 foreach ($userItems_get as $item => $value) {

            if ($value['prefab'] == 'wearable') {

            echo $value['name'] . "</br>";

            echo "<img src=\"{$value['image_inventory']}.png\" width=\"90\" height=\"60\">" . "</br>";

            if (!isset($value['item_rarity'])) {
                $rarity = "common";
            } else {
                $rarity = $value['item_rarity'];
            }

            echo $rarity . "</br>";

            foreach ($userItemsLoad as $key => $values) {

                if ($item == $values['defindex']) {

                    echo $values['id'] . "</br></br>";
                    break;
                }

            }

            }


        }
```

I want it to display like this: http://puu.sh/l7gyH/afe812c4f3.jpg

for which i have this html:

```
<div class="item-container">
    <div id="item-box">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-95-60-9.jpg" alt="">

              <div id="rarity">
                    rare
              </div>
          </div>
```

Which ever items the user selects i want to gets it values['id'], the user maybe select multiple items at once.

I can create a normal checkpoint type input table but the user might have 1000's of items so it needs to this way like in the picture.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item-container">
    <div class="item-box" data-id="1234">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-95-60-9.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="rarity">
            rare
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var selectedItems = [];

    $('.item-box').on('click', function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var selectedItems = []
        $('.item-box.selected').each(function(i,o){
            selectedItems.push($(this).data('id'))
        })
    });
</script>
```

Personally thought I would think about using AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/) for something like this, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I'm a little confused, how will this work.. also what is data-id? and what is the form type, input type in this? can u implement the loop into this? it would save me alot of time. how can i make a table like that?

Comment: data-id is the values['id'] you supply for each item.  What it does is applies/removes the selected class (which you can then have a visual representation of).  It is not anything in a form, but when you post the form you can use the variable selectedItems which is an array of the selected ID's.

Comment: So i tired and this is my code right now: http://pastebin.com/rQecdZDA this is the output: http://puu.sh/l7mJo/9d602d81c1.jpg I am not able to select any item and theres no button to submit the data also i cant see my selections.

Comment: You need to change id="item-box" to class="item-box". See this fiddle - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOyXOW . You then need to add that to the data that is submitted when you submit the form (if that is what you are doing)

Comment: Really sorry to ask again but i think im missing something, it still wont select when i click on it, this is my code right now: http://pastebin.com/g6fkLTcb . I think the problem might be that item-box is already a defined class in my css, which modfiys the look of the box like this: http://puu.sh/l7J9N/7d98f7c710.jpg I cant see anything selected. how to fix this?

Comment: Use a different class name then, and replace wherever it is referenced in my code.